# Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): Expected space separating root-level values

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash filter by grok and import log file into elasticsearch. I want to split my log file into 4 parts which are time, log-level, class(edited: sorry my bad, it is thread, not class) and message.

Below are a few lines of my log file generated by spring-boot using lob-back.xml

```
2019-09-17 16:25:01,116 INFO  [main]: org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler:initialize:Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2019-09-17 16:25:01,225 INFO  [main]: org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor:initialize:Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
[2019-09-17T16:25:01,425][ERROR][logstash.codecs.json] JSON parse error, original data now in message field {:error=>#<LogStash::Json::ParserError:
Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): Expected space separating root-level values
"; line: 1, column: 6]>, :data=>"2019-09-17 16:25:01,043 INFO  [main]: org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain:<init>:Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/v2/api-docs'], []\r"}
```

My logstash configuration:

```
input { 
    file { 
        path => "C:/data/log/*.log" 
        codec => "json" 
        type => "logback" 
    } 
} 

filter {
    grok { 
        match => { 
            "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:log-level} [%{DATA:class}]: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" 
        } 
    } 
} 

output {
    if [type]=="logback" {
        elasticsearch { 
            hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ] 
            index => "logback-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: input { file { path => "C:/data/log/*.log" codec => "json" type => "logback" } } filter { grok {match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:log-level} [%{DATA:class}]: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" } } } output { if [type]=="logback" { elasticsearch { hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ] index => "logback-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" } } }

Comment: above are my logstash.conf

Comment: You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57970609/edit) and add the relevant information intead of adding a comment. Also, selecting the code and hitting "Ctrl+K" will format it a bit.

Comment: The issue is coming from the `codec => json` in your input. This option means that logstash, when reading a line from the file, will try to parse that line as json; since your line isn't json, it's not working, causing the `LogStash::Json::ParserError` in your logs. Removing the `codec => json` option in your input should fix this.

Comment: @baudsp Thanks for helping me editing the question! After removing the "codec => json" it still has some problem but I manage to fix it, the problem was my grok filter, after I change [%{DATA:class}] to %{DATA:class}, it works perfectly.

Comment: @bradbury9 Thanks, it was my first time posting question, I was a bit confuse.

Comment: If you want to use `[]` in your grok pattern, you'll have escape them, like this: `\[%{DATA:class}\]`. (and as a side note, in that kind of log pattern `[main]` usually refers to a thread name, not a class)

Comment: @baudsp Thanks for the info, after playing around with grok filter, finally I know what it talking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape [] characters to consider them like part of string, not like special characters

```
match => {
  "message" => '^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:log_level}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:thread}\]: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}$'
}
```

I've update your pattern with a few improvements:

- Set **start(^) and end($) of line anchors** to raise regex performance,
  because failure will be faster. More info about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/do-you-grok-grok).
- Your logs have 2 space between "log-level" and "class" (in fact, it is thread, not class). If it is not permanent amount of spaces (sometimes Spring fill a log variable up to some length), it is better to use **%{SPACE} mask**.
- Follow [es name convention](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/devguide/current/event-conventions.html) for "log-level" variable:

  - Use snake case (**underscores)** for combining words.

Comment: Thanks! Using your answer and playing around with it, now I know what the grok filter talking about.

Comment: Can you help me parse this

"message" => ["%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:[system][syslog][timestamp]} %{SYSLOGHOST:[system][syslog][hostname]} %{DATA:[system][syslog][program]}(?:\[%{POSINT:[system][syslog][pid]}\])?: %{GREEDYMULTILINE:[system][syslog][message]}"]